# Default gas value in eth.sendTransaction

Tags: gas

Here's the [link](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) to the docs.

Here's an example I have some problems with:

```
 // compiled solidity source code using https://chriseth.github.io/cpp-ethereum/
  var code = "603d80600c6000396000f3007c01000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000350463c6888fa18114602d57005b6007600435028060005260206000f3";

 web3.eth.sendTransaction({data: code}, function(err, address) {
     if (!err)
     console.log(address); // "0x7f9fade1c0d57a7af66ab4ead7c2eb7b11a91385"
 });
```

What I can't understand is:

1. How much gas will be spent by this transaction?
2. Are there any other resources that provide any additional information on the topic?